# Hibernate does not persist all fields of an object

Tags: hibernate, jpa, merge, persistence, dropwizard

I have the following Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Example")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)


public class Example  implements Comparable<Example>, Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @JsonProperty
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    long id;

    String fieldToPersist;
}
```

Its DAO

```
public class ExampleDAO {



    public SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public Session session;

    public ExampleDAO(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        this.session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    }


    @Transactional
    public void createOrSave(Example ex) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Example exExisting = getById(ex.id);
        try {
            if (exExisting != null) {
                session.merge(ex);
                tx.commit();
            } else {
                session.save(ex);
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            tx.rollback();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

    }
```

In my code

I set

```
example.setFieldToPersist("abc")
dao.createOrsave(example);
```

For some reason this does not persist in the database. I see the call being made to the DAO method and I see no errors in the logs. But this field is not saved in the database ( although the object is saved)

I believe there is some problem with the `session.merge()` call. If I remove it so that it only saves the object, it creates a new row for the object but the new fields are saved. Is there something that I am missing?

I also noticed that the first time I make a change to the object and call the createOrSave() method, it correctly updates the object. But future calls to this method dont seem to update it?? Does the session get stale? Should the logs give some information on this?

I also verfied the value of the field just before the call to merge and it is the new value. Why is this not reflected in the database?

I have also tried the follwoing methods instead of merge

```
session.save() -- creates a new entry in the database with the updated values
session.update() - no change
session.saveOrUpdate() -- no change
session.flush() -- no change
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your createOrSave method to something like this:

```
@Transactional
public void createOrSave(Example ex) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    //saving the getById on another variable
    Example managedExample = getById(ex.id);

    try {
        if (managedExample != null) {
            //if the entity exists, just merge
            session.merge(ex);

        } else {
            session.save(ex);
        }
        tx.commit();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        tx.rollback();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, Changed it but that doesnt seem to fix the issue

Comment: Could you also try calling 

`Example ex = getById(ex.id); `

After:

`Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();`

Comment: same issue, tried getting the object after trabsaction begin

Comment: Is there an annotation that needs to be set on the getters?

Comment: You can put  `@Column` on your getter/atributte. In this annotation you can specifiy if the collumn is updatable

Comment: When you mention: **first time I make a change to the object and call the createOrSave() ** this is when you are persisting the entity? On a update flow, when you call `Example ex = getById(ex.id);` you lose the property you previous set (before calling createOrSave).

Comment: Does it matter though ? this attribute will be useful once there is stuff in the database, correct?

Comment: I create the object , and update it. It works fine. After I make the second update it does not save the state

Comment: @user_mda I edited the answer. My guess is that when you try to update your entity, you lose the changes because `Example ex = getById(ex.id);`. Please, check if that solution works.

Comment: I am going to try the change. But I am only getting the entity using its ID and then 'merging' it with this changed copy of the entity. Do you still think I will lose the changes? Also I update many fields so a method for each field isnt feasible?

Comment: Yes, given that you are assign `ex`  `getById(ex.id)`. you will lose any change you made. In that case, to don't need to update many fields on you entity, you can pass you variable to `merge`. I made another edit on the answer.